# Subset problem - discrete mathematic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why A = {a} ⊆ {{a}, b, c} = B is wrong?

Because a isn't an element of B but set a ({a}) is an element of B?

Comment: Change names ${{{{{}}}}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $\{a\}$ is an element of $\{\{a\},b,c\}$, not a subset.

However, note that $\{a\}$ is an element and a subset of $\{a,\{a\}\}$.